# availability-groups

Tags: availability-groups

I was in the process of configuring aag on two new 2014 Enterprise servers. The configuration going good and the cluster, the nodes, the listener, the fileshare witness are online. Everything seems normal and I can failover from one node to another. However the second node showed not joining the aag. When I tried to join it using ssms, the following error is displayed.
[image]

What is in the SQL SERVER Error log stated as follows.
"Database Mirroring login attempt by user '*' failed with error: 'Connection handshake failed. The login '*' does not have CONNECT permission on the endpoint."

I also search for an answer and based on what I got, I create a login  MYDOMAINNAME\svc_sqlserver on both nodes and grant hadr_endpoint to it. When I tried again the issue is not resolved. It seems permission issue but I couldn't figure out it.

Comment: Have you checked these?  Permissions (Server Instance)
Taken from - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878487(v=sql.120).aspx#PermissionsSI
--Creating the database mirroring endpoint Requires CREATE ENDPOINT permission, or membership in the sysadmin fixed server role. Also requires CONTROL ON ENDPOINT permission. For more information, see GRANT Endpoint Permissions (Transact-SQL). 
Enabling AlwaysOn Availability Groups Requires membership in the Administrator group on the local computer and full control on the WSFC cluster.

Comment: All what you mentioned are true and I was following these facts. However I grant the permission for the login svc_sqlserver. When I tried to grant for admin account the , message I got is "Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself."

Comment: Is the service account the same for both instances? What @RobVarn said is true and it's a permissions issue. Check the application event log as well, you'll see similar information about not having permissions.